# send email as root in Debian

Tags: debian, root, exim

[solved]

I have a problem while sending email as root from Debian machine. In exim panic log appears message:

> 2009-10-23 10:56:24 1N1Fwd-0001v5-Kh User 0 set for my_local_delivery_transport transport is on the fixed_never_users list

I've added to /etc/aliases:

> root: contact@external.domain

But problem still persist.

Have somebody faced with type of issue?

[solved]

a) It works with sudo:

```
sudo -u user mail -s test mail@addre.ss
```

b) It works with aliases (I forgot to issue newaliases command, thanks blank3)

Comment: After editing /etc/aliases you have to run newaliases command.

Comment: Just FYI: It's generally considered bad style to do "regular stuff" (read manpages, send mail) as root. You can use a regular account, and just su/sudo to root when needed. But of course sending mail as root should work anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you use `su` or `sudo` to send the mail as another user?

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in. It works with sudo: sudo -u user mail -s test mail@addre.ss

Comment: Great. It's safer that way also.

Answer (score 0):

Due to security concerns Exim4 will not send mail as root by default 
Search your config for "fixed_never_users" and remove root from the list or su/sudo to a non-privileged user when sending mail.

Comment: Seems that list of users that it specifies is built into the binary, and cannot be changed